# How to fix Ioncube undetecting problem on ubuntu and apache webserver?

Tags: apache, server, webserver, ioncube, php-7.0

I tried to install ioncube on my Ubuntu server using the instructions available on the Internet, but despite all the steps, I was not able to set it up, and there is still an error that there is no ioncube on my browser. please guide me.
It should be noted that I use the Apache web server
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hke1K.png)

Comment: Please don't post text as image, and check [help/on-topic] to make this question more on topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Try the ionCube Loader Wizard script. It's an expert system that will query your server configuration, use knowledge of certain special cases, and advise on what to do. It will also attempt to identify problems in the setup.